# I wanted to used SaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-savedstate

I wanted to use SavedInstanceState to save the data of the Recycler View and other associated data I have like the title etc.(This is a cart Activity basically where all the data gets collected from other Activity)
My code:-

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import com.example.myapplication.passing_data
import java.lang.Class
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class TrackOrderAcitivty : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var adapter3: ImageAdapter
    private  lateinit var ImageRecyclerView : RecyclerView
    private  lateinit var DataArraylist : ArrayList<images>
    private lateinit var savedArrayList:ArrayList<passing_data>
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("Total Saved List",savedArrayList)
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("Image Saved List",DataArraylist)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_order_acitivty)
        DataArraylist= arrayListOf<images>()
        val food:passing_data = intent.getParcelableExtra("foodie")!!
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){

            savedArrayList.addAll(savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("Total Saved List",passing_data))
        }
        if(food!=null)
        {
            savedArrayList.add(passing_data(food.Image,food.title,food.category,food.price,food.star_rating,food.count))
            DataArraylist.add(images(food.Image))
            val order:TextView=findViewById(R.id.textView16)
            order.text="${food.count} Items Ordered"
            val layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
            ImageRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Image)
            ImageRecyclerView.layoutManager= layoutManager
            ImageRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter3= ImageAdapter(DataArraylist)
            ImageRecyclerView.adapter= adapter3
        }

    }
}
```

In Line no 31 I wanted to get the content of my saved Parcelable Array list back into it as if I reopen Activity all of it just gets removed.

On Addition:
Also I had found that there is something known as `ChangeNumberItemListener` in Java which basically saves the content of a Recycler View so I wanted to know how to implement that in Kotlin.

If I can implement this I can basically avoid saving ArrayList all together.

Answer (score 1):

The error I think is because you are not initializing the `savedArrayList` in any place. Consider replacing this:

```kotlin
private lateinit var savedArrayList: ArrayList<passing_data>
```

With This:

```kotlin
private var savedArrayList = arrayListOf<passing_data>()
```

Or just initialize it after the `DataArraylist`

Regarding your second question, Android or Java has no built-in `ChangeNumberItemListener`. It's possible that you have come across some custom implementation of this listener with a Recycler View, and yeah you can do the same in kotlin.

Comment: Even after initializing my savedArrayList the exact error given by Android Studio is as follows: 1.)Type mismatch: inferred type is ArrayList<(???..???)>? but Collection<passing_data> was expected  2.)Type mismatch: inferred type is passing_data.CREATOR but Class<out TypeVariable(T)!> was expected